# How to check if UUID is null, empty or blank?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, uuid

I have a Springboot application and my entity have a field `id` and `ownerId` which is type of UUID.
How can i check if the UUID is actually a UUID and not a string or anything else?

My example code:

```
when {
            project.id != null -> handleIllegalParameter("id")
            project.ownerId != null -> handleIllegalParameter("ownerId")
            project.name.isNullOrBlank() -> handleMissingRequiredField("name")

        }
```

How can I can check that is actually a UUID and not a string, integer or anything else except UUID?

Comment: Are those fields defined as from type `UUID`? You could then check if `project.id is UUID`.

Comment: How can i check if `project.id` is null or blank in kotlin way?

Comment: you could transform to `String` and check `project.id.toString().isNullOrBlank()`.

Comment: In addition, you might like to check if it is a Nil UUID too. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-4.1.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `id` and `ownerId` are of type `UUID?` then once you check they are not null - you are good. If they of type `String` (as the title of your question implies) you can use the `UUID.fromString()` method that throws `IllegalArgumentException` if the conversion fails.